# UWP Unlocking App for Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, lockscreen

I can't find any information about how to create an app to unlock my phone. It should replace the simple pin input. Is there any posibility in the UWP Framework and have any one of you any experiences with it?

Comment: As far as i know - no

Comment: In UWP, no. There was briefly a private API for creating custom lockscreen apps for Windows Phone 8 Silverlight, but I believe that no longer works on Windows Mobile 10 either.

Comment: I think it can be done using [Windows Hello API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/microsoft-passport) because [Samsung Flow](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/samsungflow/) can unlock the computer. Recommended article to read [Windows Unlock with Windows Hello companion (IoT) devices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/companion-device-unlock).